# Execute command from Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute a script from Java program:

```
public class TestCommandLine 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String PATH = "/path/programs/";
        String command = PATH + "name_programs param1 param2";
        executeCommand (command);
    }

    private static String executeCommand (String command) 
    {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        Process p;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (command);
            p.waitFor ();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream ()));


            while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
                output.append (line + "\n");
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        return output.toString ();
    }
}
```

there is not error, but the program does not run. I also try others solutions from stackoverflow but all of them didn't work

Comment: start with some statements for debugging (or step through with a proper debugger). Print out the command string first. If you copy paste the string does it work manually in cmd line? You are also calling `executeCommand` but not capturing the return string. What does that string consist of? How are you certain the program does not run? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Already done. I've printed out my command in the console, copied it and pasted it in the command line where the command works correctly

Comment: Check exitValue and the contents of getErrorStream(). That's where errors would be indicated.

Comment: I've added this: System.out.println ("Exit: " + p.exitValue()); and the exit value is 1. And the getErrorStream() is "Error: java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@7559f3f0". In fact, I used the command in this way: "path/program/nameProgram input > output"

Comment: If you're redirecting the output, how do you expect to receive any in your `reader`?

Comment: java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@7559f3f0 is the stream. You have to read from it like you are with the other stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd given your actual command to start with, this would have been much quicker.

You cannot use `Process.exec` to run shell-interpreted commands. Instead it executes programs directly. Thus input/output redirection (`|`, `>`, etc.) is not possible.
If you actually read the stderr (`getErrorStream()`) output it would probably be along the lines of "invalid argument: >".

You will either have to:

- Redirect the output in Java. Read from the process's stdout (`getInputStream()`) and write to a FileOutputStream of some kind.
- Execute a shell instead of your command directly. For example `/bin/sh -c "command arg > file"`. The quoted section must be passed to `sh` as a single argument. In this case you wouldn't be able to see anything in stdout, and would have to open and read the file you just wrote to. The first option is probably more sensible.

And as pointed out elsewhere, unless your expecting a very small amount of output, you shouldn't wait for the command to exit before consuming the streams.

Answer (score -1):

The only time I've done it I've used something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo.exe");
```

Have you tried that?  If so, what was the error you got back?

Comment: The method "executeCommand (String command)" contains the function that you've wrote. I have not exception. I have no error

Answer (score -1):

Your command is producing output that you want to read, but you refuse to read any of it until the command has finished producing it all and has exited (not calling `getInputStream()` until *after* `waitFor()`).

If your command doesn't produce much output, this is OK, Java can buffer it. But if your command produces a lot of output, Java can't buffer it all, and the command gets blocked.

The operating system won't let the command write any more output because Java's buffer is full and you haven't instructed Java to empty it. So the program is blocked, and Java's `waitFor()` will never come back.

To solve your problem, you should call `getInputStream()` immediately after getting the `Process` object back from `exec()`, and you should create a new `Thread` that is responsible for reading the command output into your `StringBuffer`.

You should then `waitFor()` the process to finish, to see if it exited successfully, and then you can wait for the thread to get to the end of the inputstream and finish - at that point, it is safe to read through the `StringBuffer` with the full output from your command.